# Please rename [sport] to [sports]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I think [sport](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport) would be better found as [sports](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports). I attempted to retag the one question using the former tag, but was given this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the [sport](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport) tag. In a little while, it will disappear and we can add the [sports](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) tag.

Comment: Just retagged the question [tag:sports]. All is well!